# Can Tetris be made without using XNA currently? Using C#?

Tags: c#, xna, tetris

I have an outdated computer, that currently will not run certain XNA components. I am a beginner at this stuff, so I'm looking to get some other programming stuff done before I get a new computer that can run XNA and everything else. But is Tetris easy to make without XNA?

Comment: I'm curious why you think XNA is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. I have written Tetris for text mode, and in ILasm at that, so it is possible.

You can work on the smarts of the game in any presentation style, then change that later.

Comment: You mean by text mode a console app?

Comment: Yes. My point to the beginner being keep it simple and return to basics, making Tetris doesn't require any advanced rendering technology. Tetris has been done on nearly every platform and every display type. I did a curses version on HPUX on a 12" WYSE green screen one summer working as a coop. The blocks fell erratically when batch jobs were running and my sys-admin was not happy to find a college kid writing games on the departmental UNIX server.

Answer (score 0):

[**Tetris Game in C#**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/avgustishechenkp/Tetris11292005020839AM/Tetris.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can write WPF and Silverlight applications in C# and they are more than capable platforms for building a Tetris game.

Here is a Tetris game developed in Silverlight. http://www.herbess.com/Projects/Silverlight.aspx

Enjoy and Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't need any advanced graphics capabilities for Tetris, and C# and GDI/GDI+ development will be fine.

[Here's some VS2003 vintage samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336739.aspx) from MS - you might examine the "Using GDI+ with C#" source code to get started